# IFrame in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, iframe, applet, mashup

We are designing an application, part of which is a mashup of UI from a web application.

Is it possible to place the UI from a web site in a WPF application, as you would an IFrame?

The web page contains a Java applet.

Comment: @casperOne, the answer from Snake was exactly the information I required.

Comment: And yet, it's still there.  Your question shows a lack of fundamental research.  And Snake's answer is a link-only answer.  Both are frowned upon on Stack Overflow.  That said, both the question and answers require *severe* maintenance as the entire thing is likely to be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx

You could use this, but it will Internet Explorer as the rendering engine, so I suppose that you need to have Java installed to use it. Be sure to test it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace and the [`WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

1. Add `ieframe.dll` to refrences
2. do like you add the `SHDocVw.WebBrowser` to the application dynamicly.
3. ???
4. Profit.

You also need to make it so your wpf application can show `COM` components.